# Convert polygons to KML file

Tags: polygon, kml, sql-server

I have a set of  polygons out of which I want to make a KML file, my table schema is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[utilitygeo](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PolygonID] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [geog] [geography] NULL
)
```

I tried extracting `Lat/Long` from each polygon and then thought of converting them into a KML file, following is the code:

```
declare @g geography;

select top 1 @g =  geog from MyDB..Geoterritory

declare @i int = 1
create table ##result(
    Latitude float,
    Longitude float
)

while @i < @g.STNumPoints()
BEGIN
    insert into ##result values(
        @g.STPointN(@i).Lat,
        @g.STPointN(@i).Long
    ) 
END

select * from ##result
```

But this takes a lot of time.
Is there a better way to generate KML file from these polygons in `SSMS`.
Thanks

Comment: do you want it programatically? or just need a conversion to kml.

Comment: just need to convert it to kml.

Comment: @snyder may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312896/generate-kml-in-sql-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to increment the @i

```
while @i < @g.STNumPoints()
BEGIN
    insert into ##result values(
        @g.STPointN(@i).Lat,
        @g.STPointN(@i).Long
    ) 

    set @i = @i + 1

END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using QGIS. Open it and `add postgis layer` after loading the layer you can right click on the layer and choose `Save As` and select `Keyhole Markup Language (KML)`. It uses GDAL to do the conversion to KML. you can see some interesting options regarding KML creation in gdal [kml driver page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_kml.html)

Comment: I am not using `QGIS`, but will try it.

Comment: This worked for me. I did not have to add a postgis layer, all I had to do was go to "Save As" and select Keyhole Markup Language (KML).